# Does rbenv work along/overrides or conflict with an apt installed ruby?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

Does rbenv work along,overrides or conflict with an apt installed ruby - and what are the implications for apt-packages that depend on ruby.

Comment: ``rbenv`` installs inside your user directory under ~/.rbenv

Comment: thx, got it, so the github.com/dcarley/rbenv-sudo makes sense. I was asking because i have an app which requires rbenv with 2.4.1 but the same app also wants to install apt packages which depend on ruby and apt pulls ruby then.

Comment: PS its a sudo environment

Comment: PPS here is the install script for rbenv to be run by the sudo user, same user intended to build and run the app which requires apt dependencies which want to pull ruby fro apt - https://hastebin.com/uzinetaseb.bash

Comment: That script is going to make a mess of your path if run more than once. Is there a way to install without running the script?

Comment: ``rbenv`` is use for multiple version of ruby and deleting the directory would mess me up.

Comment: the script was intended to make a blanc install, ignore the rm  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Linux machine it is normal that even some WM depend on ruby. That should not discourage your use of rbenv and/or rvm. I personally use rvm and my colleague uses rbenv while we both have apps dependent on ruby from apt.

**Conclusion:**
Be careful how you setup your PATH and where you put your rbenv, but there should be no collision what so ever between them because the ruby that is installed as a dependency is not even executable by you. (Just be careful to not overdo it with sudo or root user. Have a user of your own for the development part)